# COUNTIFS referencing another sheet

Tags: excel, countif

My Fourmula: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(BRIDGE!H2:H500,">50",H2:H500,"<75" ))`

Trying to count values greater than 50 but less than 75 on another sheet named "Bridge". The problem, this is just counting on the sheet the formula is on, not the referenced sheet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(BRIDGE!H2:H500,">50",BRIDGE!H2:H500,"<75" ))`?

Comment: works! great! thank you!

Comment: Also, I don't see why you need the `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: yea i dont think i need that thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your formula you do not refer to the "Bridge" tab on the second range of the `CountIfS` formula. It should be like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(BRIDGE!H2:H500,">50",BRIDGE!H2:H500,"<7‌​5" ))`

Comment: I think all you need is this: `=COUNTIFS(BRIDGE!H2:H500,">50",BRIDGE!H2:H500,"<7‌​5" )`